# Time measuring accuracy

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, performance, time

By implementing the line

```
start_time = time.time()
```

at the start of my code and

```
print("%f seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

at the end of my code I have been measuring the performance of my script (which can take hours to run). I have heard that this may not be the best method due to it being inaccurate. How accurate is it and is there a better alternative?

Comment: On a time-scale of hours, any subsecond accuracy seems irrelevant. How accurate do you want your timings to be?

Comment: Disregard that figure. I came for recommendations of the best method. Cheers

Comment: The "best method" is somewhat subjective. The best method may cost $200K, and may thus not be the best method for your wallet. Also, do you want to measure wall-clock time, CPU time? Please make your question more practical.

Comment: Good point. Sorry for my vagueness.

Comment: `datetime.datetime` instances have a `microsecond` attribute that will be used if you use `datetime.datetime.now()`. So do `timedelta` instances.The accuracy of `time.time()` is OS dependent—on some it's less than 1 second.

Comment: Don't make your question more practical, make it more concrete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, timeit from the standard library:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
start_time = timer()
end_time = timer()    
print(end_time - start_time)                                                                                                                                           
logger.info("Duration was {}".format(end_time - start_time))
```

The documentation for default_timer is of interest, and should really be quoted in the answer: "Define a default timer, in a platform-specific manner. On Windows, time.clock() has microsecond granularity, but time.time()’s granularity is 1/60th of a second. On Unix, time.clock() has 1/100th of a second granularity, and time.time() is much more precise. On either platform, default_timer() measures wall clock time, not the CPU time. This means that other processes running on the same computer may interfere with the timing."

Comment: Could you specify why this is a better option regarding accuracy? Thanks

Comment: The documentation for `default_timer` is of interest, and should really be quoted in the answer: "Define a default timer, in a platform-specific manner. On Windows, time.clock() has microsecond granularity, but time.time()’s granularity is 1/60th of a second. On Unix, time.clock() has 1/100th of a second granularity, and time.time() is much more precise. On either platform, default_timer() measures wall clock time, not the CPU time. This means that other processes running on the same computer may interfere with the timing."

Comment: Awesome thanks for that. I will edit your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try usng datetime

```
from datetime import datetime
startTime = datetime.now()
#CODE
print("Time taken:",datetime.now() - startTime)
```

Comment: Could you specify why this is a better option regarding accuracy? Thanks